# Execute script only on certain admin pages

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script

To solve this problem i've used this in my js file:

```
var location = String(window.location);

//only runs in post.php and post-new.php
if(location.search('post.php') != -1 || location.search('post-new.php') != -1 )
{

}
```

But it's does not seem like i solid solution. Are there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in your `functions.php` :

```
function add_admin_scripts( $hook ) {

    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' ) {

        wp_enqueue_script(  'myscript', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/myscript.js' );

    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','add_admin_scripts',10,1);
```

Comment: What does, 10,1 in the add_action function means?

Comment: `10` is the priority; `1` represents the number of variables passed to the callback.

Comment: Note: you could also use the `$pagenow` global, using the same approach.